# The simple groups with an absolutely irreducible projective representations with small degrees

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

In the question "Simple Hurwitz Groups of order less than 10^7", it came up that all the Hurwitz groups with absolutely irreducible projective representations of degrees up to 7 over any field are determined (This later turned out to be false).

I was wondering, exactly what are all the simple groups with absolutely irreducible projective representations of degrees up to 7 over any field? Also, for which of those classes of groups is it determined which ones are hurwitz groups?

Comment: The published tables of Hiss and Malle (coprime characteristic) and Lubeck (defining characteristic) contain complete classifications up to dimension $250$.

Comment: Concerning which ones are Hurwitz groups, I don't think you are going to get any more information than was in the answers and comments to your previous question. It is all in the literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The references for the low-dimensional projective representations of quasisimple groups are:

G. Hiss and G. Malle,
`Low dimensional representations of quasi-simple groups',
LMS J. Comput. Math. 4 (2001) 22-63. [Corrigenda: LMS J. Comput. Math. 5 (2002) 95-126].

F. Lübeck,
`Small degree representations of finite Chevalley groups in defining
characteristic',
LMS J. Comput. Math. 4 (2001) 135-169.

Comment: Note that the 2002 paper by Hiss-Malle contains a complete corrected list.   The journal is freely available here: http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayIssue?iid=6564372

Comment: Well it's complete apart from a few generic cases like ${\rm (P)SL}(2,q)$. Fortunately the LMS JCM is open access.